# jQuery stops event propagation in IE by default even when *true* is returned in .delegate event handler

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have to look for clicks on anchor tags, as and when they happen and log them.
The jQuery delegate event handler for clicks is stopping the default behaviour of links in IE (*i.e clicking on links doesnt take me to a new page, or whatever the link was really supposed to do*), whereas in Firefox things work just fine.

I would be glad if anyone from the community can help me figure this out.

CODE SAMPLE:

```
function logLink(event,target)
{
    //no logging for right click
    if(event.which<3)
    {
        if(filterLinks(target))
        {
            alert('This will log data');
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/*
 *Method to filter all html links which are  to be logged 
 */
function filterLinks(linkObj)
{
    //go into second phase only if the passed object is a link.
    if(linkObj.tagName == 'A')
    {
        alert('second phase')
        if( linkObj.hostname==undefined ||linkObj.hostname==''|| linkObj.hostname==null  || $(linkObj).attr('href')=='#' || (!$(linkObj).attr('href')) || $(linkObj).attr('href').beginsWith('javascript',true) ||  $(linkObj).attr('href').beginsWith('mailto',true)) 
        {
            alert('native code');
            $(linkObj).css('background','gray');
            return false;
        }
        for(var i=0;i<linkObj.attributes.length;i++)
        {
            if( !$.browser.msie && anchorTagProperties.indexOf(linkObj.attributes[i].nodeName)<0 )
            {
                alert('redenned tag has an unknown attribute' + linkObj.attributes[i].nodeName);
                $(linkObj).css('background','red');
                return false;
            }


        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

$(function (){

var testVar=undefined;

//adding delegate listener for trackedLink class
$('body').delegate(".trackedLink", "mouseup", function(event){
        alert('mouseup'); 
        var returnValue =logLink(event,this);
        return true;
});

});
```

Comment: would you please post some code sample.

Comment: Have you tried not returning anything (i.e. remove `return true`)? Maybe there is also a problem with the `alert`... try removing that too.

Comment: There was no return true there earlier, but before I posted a problem like this to stackoverflow, I wanted to confirm if adding that would change the behaviour.So, actually the origianal code was without the return statements.The alerts, ill try removing and let you know.

Comment: Removing the alerts seems to work like a charm.Thanks a lot again Felix.Though I could not understand why this should happen, it would be good if you could post an answer to the same and make it a community wiki , for further reference.