# Detect external link Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How can i detect external link click?**

I have a simple question, which may or may not have an simple answer. I need to detect if some of my page's user's have clicked an external link, an ad for example.

My first tought was that i would place an random number of transparent div's over a specific link so an user should click on it until he'll get redirected to a new page but that would be inconvievnant for users and would still be exploitable.

I hope that you guys can help me out and i'll do my best to help you out one day.

Sorry for my english as my native language isn't english.

Comment: First question: by "external" you mean link inside iframe? Second question: you want to detect it and then what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with jquery, select all external links and an handler for click event:

```
// Creating custom :external selector
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
            && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
};

// Manage clicks on external links
$('a:external').click(function() {
    // do your stuff here, ie send the link href to some server-side script
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "some.php", data: "href="+$(this).attr("href") });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was useful! I also had to check (href === "") in order to exclude those anchors without href.

Comment: For Google Analytics it should be like this:
```var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
   return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
           && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
 };
 $('a:external').click(function() {
   trackOutboundLink($(this).attr("href"));
 });
});```

Answer (score 1):

Hey, you really need to use google analytics.
Incase you do not want to do that, check this out.
[Logging hyperlink clicks on my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658442/logging-hyperlink-clicks-on-my-website)

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/ this is pretty neat tool for logging link clicks as well as some other stuff.And all you would really need to do is simply add a few lines of code at the end of each html page on the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can track outbound clicks that do not belong to the current site by doing the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', 'a[href^="http"]:not([href*="//' + location.host + '"])', function(){
        if (typeof(_gaq) !== 'undefined') {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound', 'click', this.href.match(/\/\/([^\/]+)/)[1]]);
            _gaq.push(['t2._trackEvent', 'outbound', 'click', this.href.match(/\/\/([^\/]+)/)[1]]);
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously you can strip out the Google Analytics `gaq` stuff if you don't need it.

Answer (score -3):

If you can add an extra class to the links you could do something like that:

```
<a href="http://www.externalsite.com/" class="external">AD</a>
```

i.e. add an "external" class to every link, and then use jquery like this:

```
$('.external').click(function(event) {
    // do something before the user gets redirected
});
```

You could also use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action (i.e. redirecting the user) and then do something else.

**EDIT**
If you can't add class="external" directly into the markup, you could add it dinamycally using jQuery using some code like:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href') is an external link) {
        $(this).addClass('external');
    }
});
```

I've not tested this second snippet but it should work.